# TYPO3 / TypoScript : how do I get an image url from page? pinterest

Tags: typo3, typoscript, pinterest

How do I get an image-url from my TYPO3-Page to share this at pinterest?

I try to share a image via pinterest. I can share my individual page via twitter and facebook, but at pinterest, I need an image url. Ho do I get my Image from Page XY? Normal content page with text and images ... my image, I want to share comes via extension.

```
<img src="typo3temp/GB/Donna_Lanea8d0434f4.jpg" width="398" height="398" border="0" alt="" title="" style="opacity: 1;">
```

I don't want to use a sociel bookmark plugin!

That's my social link, it works for facebook and google+, twitter, ..

```
...
lib.social = COA
lib.social {


15 = TEXT
15 {
    wrap = <li class="social_two">|</li>
    value = Pinterest
    typolink.title = Pin it on Pinterest
    typolink.ATagParams = class="social pt"  target="_blank"
    typolink.parameter.cObject = COA
    typolink.parameter.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.dataWrap = http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=|
        10.data = getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_URL
   }
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I hope you are aware that you create an XSS security hole on your website if you use getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_URL without htmlspecialchars. Also you should not use dataWrap if you do not have data to interprete. I suggest to use ``typolink`` instead: http://typo3.org/documentation/snippets/sd/131/ (just remove the ``,98`` from the parameter).

Answer (score 0):

I use the following snippit and it works. No TypoScript.

```
<a class="social pt" href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
            Pin it on Pinterest or your image
        </a>
```